# How to use <br> tag in Dbms_output.put_line(''); in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have the query which i used in an application for which i am having difficulty in using 
 tag in PL/SQL. The query is:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(last_name, 'br') WITHIN group (ORDER BY last_name) 
into lastname from employees;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lastname);
```

Output I got is: `Abel br Ande br Baer br`

Output I want: 

 Abel
Ande
Baer

Comment: Try using `';<br>'` instead.

Comment: @vkp: you sure this works? do you have any link to documentation for it? I just tried it, not working for me ... I don't think Oracle has any special handling for `<br>` ...  please link to any relevant documentation, however, would love to learn something new :)

Comment: Or use a cursor loop calling `dbms_output.put_line` once per `employees.lastname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"br" has no special meaning within Oracle that I'm aware of, use CHR(10) (ie Carriage Return) instead.  (or CHR(10)+CHR(13) if working in Windows)

```
    1  with w_data as ( select level id from dual connect by level <= 10 )
    2  select listagg ( id, chr(10) ) within group (order by id )
    3*   from w_data
  SQL> /

  LISTAGG(ID,CHR(10))WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYID)
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10


  1 row selected.
```

Note how it shows "1 row selected", but things are broken into seperate lines ... I believe this is the effect you are after ?

[edit] sorry, just realized you're in pl/sql .. here's the same test query in pl/sql, via dbms_output ... :

```
  declare
     lv_str   varchar2(4000);
  begin

  with w_data as ( select level id from dual connect by level <= 10 )
  select listagg ( id, chr(10) ) within group (order by id )
    into lv_str
    from w_data;

  dbms_output.put_line ( lv_str );
  end;
  /

  "gg.sql" 15 lines, 259 characters

  SQL> @gg
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10

  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks Ditto for the answer... Please let me know how to improve the skills in Oracle as i am the beginner